# grep: finding a string that starts and ends with a specific letter in directory

Tags: linux, grep

I am teaching myself commands and different ways to use grep. I know how to search for a string in a directory and its sub directories, but I am confused when it comes to searching for a split in the string.

for example: how could I search for all words (string size varies) that starts with a and ends with e. so that I could find ape or apple in text files?

EDIT UPDATE:
I am not sure of the grep version I am using, but I tried using:

" grep -nr "a[A-Za-z]*e" "

this produces the answer by including outputs like ape and apple but it also includes apes which is NOT wanted.

Comment: What characters can appear between the a and e? Any uppercase or lowercase letter?

Comment: What do you consider a word to be?

Comment: @rici essentially just a string of any characters.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick at this moment just uppercase or lowercase letters.

Comment: Those answers are mutually incompatible.

Comment: @rici that is correct. My misunderstanding. In this case, a word is just a string of letters.

Comment: Which variant of `grep` do you have?  You want to find `ape` but reject `tape` and `apes` and `grapes`?  You might have punctuation or digits or spaces before or after the word?  Things are notationally easier if you have a PCRE-enabled version of `grep`.  If you need to stick to `grep -E` (aka `egrep`), it is notationally harder but doable.  If you have to stick with plain `grep`, it is rather difficult (verging on impossible, I think).

Comment: @rici: The `-w` option to [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) is not standardized by POSIX 2008 (2016).

Comment: @jonathan: true, but most grep's implement it. However, it might not be the word boundary desired. Otoh, `grep -E` is in posix.

Comment: @rici: It's a question of choosing your standard, and the nice thing is that there are so many standards to choose from.  De facto, you're probably correct (BSD and GNU `grep` both support `-w`; but they also both support `-z` except they do different things when given that option).

Comment: I am sorry for having such a basic understanding, but i posted an edit that produces an answer very similar to the desired result. Maybe this can help give an idea of what can be corrected

Answer (score 1):

#### Simply:

```
grep '\ba\w*e\b'
```

or

```
grep --color '\ba\w*e\b'
```

or

```
grep -rn '\ba\w*e\b'
```

#### Some explanations

- As this question is tagged [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), this answer use *`GNU grep`*:  `grep (GNU grep) 2.27`.
- The result of command `man grep | grep -3 '\\b'`:

  > ```
  > The Backslash Character and Special Expressions
  >     The  symbols  \<  and  \>  respectively  match  the empty string at the
  >     beginning and end of a word.  The symbol \b matches the empty string at
  >     the  edge  of a word, and \B matches the empty string provided it's not
  >     at the edge of a word.  The symbol \w is a synonym for [_[:alnum:]] and
  >     \W is a synonym for [^_[:alnum:]].
  > ```

  Let you show

  - `\b` mean *edge of a word*
  - `\w` mean `[_[:alnum:]]`
  - `a` and `e` are letters
  - you may already know`*` wich mean *The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.* (elsewhere in same man page: `man grep | grep '^ *\*'` ;)
  - ... and finally... This could by written:

    ```
    grep '\<a\w*e\>'
    ```

    where

    > The  symbols  \<  and  >  respectively  match  the empty string at the beginning and end of a word.

    This could have near *same effect*, but description strictly correspond to title of this: ***grep: finding a string that starts and ends with a specific letter in directory***

Comment: This assumes the use of GNU or BSD `grep` — but doesn't give that caveat.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; | grep 'a[A-Za-z]\+e'
```

That should cat any .txt files in the current directory, recursively, and grep for "a... any characters... e"

The `[A-Za-z]` searches for a character of either case, the `\+` says "any number of them".

I think that's what you're after?

Edit:

Word boundaries:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \+ | grep '\ba[A-Za-z]\+e\b'
```

Comment: That will match `are` in `bared` which might not be what is desired. And you want `\;`, not `;\ `

Comment: Suppose the input contains `I will tape the apes eating grapes`; it contains three sequences `a[A-Za-z]*e`, but they aren't words.

Comment: @rici: He probably needs `+` instead of `\;` :D

Comment: Note that the `\+` and `\b` notations are non-standard extensions to `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in various comments, it is possible to do this using POSIX standard [`grep -E`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), but it is not all that notationally convenient.

I used a script file `grep-ape.sh` containing:

```
grep -E -e '(^|[^[:alpha:]])a[[:alpha:]]+e($|[^[:alpha:]])' "$@"
```

The `-E` enables extended regular expressions.  The `-e` is optional, but allows me to add extra options as 'file names' after the regular expression.  The regular expression looks for either 'start of line' or a non-alpha character, followed by `a`, one or more additional alpha characters, an `e` and either 'end of line' or a non-alpha character.

Given the data file (called, unimaginatively, `data`):

```
I want to tape the apes that ate the grapes.
ape at the start.
Ending with ape
Situating ape in the middle
And an apple too.
But not apples, no way.
The tape ran out.
The apes ran out.
The grapes ran out.
They ate them.
```

I could run `grep-ape.sh -n data` (demonstrating the usefulness of the `-e` option, though GNU systems will permute options so you don't necessarily spot the problem), and got:

```
1:I want to tape the apes that ate the grapes.
2:ape at the start.
3:Ending with ape
4:Situating ape in the middle
5:And an apple too.
10:They ate them.
```

Using a non-POSIX option `-o` (supported by GNU and BSD versions of `grep`) to print only what is matched, I can get the output:

```
$ grep-ape.sh -n -o data
1: ate 
2:ape 
3: ape
4: ape 
5: apple 
10: ate 
$
```

This shows that the regular expression is picking up the acceptable words, even on lines where there are words that would not be acceptable when not in the company of words that are acceptable.